# How to run the test scripts in Mulitple browsers parallely?

Tags: c#, selenium-webdriver, visual-studio-2015, specflow

I am beginner in Selenium testing with spec flow using VS 2015 c#. How to run the test scripts in  Multiple browsers parallel? Can anybody help me on this?

Answer (score 1):

Be careful running test cases simultaneously. If you have web apps under test with a user login and the same user is logged in twice at the same time, the test cases might interfere with each other.

Running several tests simultaneously is an issue of your test runner resp. your test framework. What are you using? NUnit? MSTest? Jenkins? TFS?

In MSTest you can create a *.testsettings file, open it in text mode and manually add the parallelTestCount param to the `<Execution>` element. Detailed description: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee921484(v=vs.100).aspx

Hope this helps!

Comment: To parallelize your SpecFlow tests you can also use the SpecFlow+Runner (SpecRun). http://www.specflow.org/plus/